# Issue with setting up basic auth header in SOAP request

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I'm using Spring Boot and I'm trying to configure web service template to append basic authentication headers on every SOAP request.

Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SoapClientConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SoapClientConfiguration.class);

    private final DmsConfiguration dmsConfiguration;

    public SoapClientConfiguration(DmsConfiguration dmsConfiguration) {
        this.dmsConfiguration = dmsConfiguration;
    }


    /**
     * Method for generating POJO objects from xml at pointed location
     *
     * @return Jaxb2Marshaller instance.
     */
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller()
    {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan(dmsConfiguration.getJaxbPackageLocation());
        return marshaller;
    }

    /**
     * Configuring DMS web service client
     *
     * @param marshaller jaxb2 marshaller
     * @return DmsWebServiceClient Object
     */
    @Bean
    public DmsWebServiceClient dmsWebServiceClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException
    {
        DmsWebServiceClient dmsWebServiceClient = new DmsWebServiceClient();
        dmsWebServiceClient.setDefaultUri(
            dmsConfiguration.getProtocol() + "://" + dmsConfiguration.getConsumerServicesUri()
        );
        dmsWebServiceClient.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        dmsWebServiceClient.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        dmsWebServiceClient.setMessageSender(defaultMessageSender());

        return dmsWebServiceClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpComponentsMessageSender defaultMessageSender()
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException
    {
        return new HttpComponentsMessageSender(createHttpClient());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient createHttpClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException
    {
        BasicHeader authHeader = new BasicHeader(
            "Authorization", "Basic " + dmsConfiguration.getBasicAuthenticationCredentials()
        );

        LOGGER.info("Web service credentials: {}", dmsConfiguration.getBasicAuthenticationCredentials());

        List<BasicHeader> authHeaders = Collections.singletonList(authHeader);
        RequestDefaultHeaders reqHeader = new RequestDefaultHeaders(authHeaders);

        return HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory())
            .addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
            .addInterceptorLast(reqHeader)
            .setDefaultHeaders(authHeaders)
            .build();
    }

    public SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory()
        throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext(), NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    }

    public SSLContext sslContext() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        return SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
            .build();
    }
}
```

and here is client configuration:

```
public class DmsWebServiceClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private DmsCallbackConfiguration dmsCallbackConfiguration;

    /**
     * Getting or creating subject
     *
     * @param subject target subject
     * @return GetOrCreateSubjectResponse Object
     */
    public GetOrCreateSubjectResponse getOrCreateSubject(GetOrCreateSubjectRequest subject)
    {
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<GetOrCreateSubjectRequest> request = objectFactory.createGetOrCreateSubjectRequest(subject);

        return (GetOrCreateSubjectResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback(dmsCallbackConfiguration.getCreateSubject()));
    }

    /**
     * Getting or creating document
     *
     * @param document target document
     * @return GetOrCreateDocumentResponse Object
     */
    public GetOrCreateDocumentResponse getOrCreateDocument(GetOrCreateDocumentRequest document)
    {
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<GetOrCreateDocumentRequest> request = objectFactory.createGetOrCreateDocumentRequest(document);

        return (GetOrCreateDocumentResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback(dmsCallbackConfiguration.getCreateDocument()));
    }

    /**
     * Inserting attachment data
     *
     * @param attachment attachment input
     * @return InsertAttachmentResponse Object
     */
    public InsertAttachmentByDocumentIdResponse uploadAttachment(InsertAttachmentByDocumentIdRequest attachment)
    {
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<InsertAttachmentByDocumentIdRequest> request
            = objectFactory.createInsertAttachmentByDocumentIdRequest(attachment);

        return (InsertAttachmentByDocumentIdResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback(dmsCallbackConfiguration.getInsertAttachment()));
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDocumentSubjectConfiguration(DmsCallbackConfiguration dmsCallbackConfiguration) {
        this.dmsCallbackConfiguration = dmsCallbackConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Communication between services works fine but I'm getting 401 Unauthorized every time I send a request.

Do you have any idea what is wrong with my code?
Thank you in advance!

P.S. I have configure the logging and here is one example request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:GetOrCreateSubjectRequest xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><ns2:Attributes><ns2:AttributeValue><ns2:IdAttribute>1084</ns2:IdAttribute><ns2:Value>test</ns2:Value></ns2:AttributeValue></ns2:Attributes><ns2:DefaultSettingsOverride>1</ns2:DefaultSettingsOverride><GetOrCreateSubjectRequest>7</GetOrCreateSubjectRequest><GetOrCreateSubjectRequest>1109953265147</GetOrCreateSubjectRequest><ns2:IdLanguage>2</ns2:IdLanguage><GetOrCreateSubjectRequest>1676</GetOrCreateSubjectRequest><ns2:IdUser>1304</ns2:IdUser><ns2:IdWorkflow>30</ns2:IdWorkflow><ns2:Name>Dosije klijenta</ns2:Name></ns2:GetOrCreateSubjectRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```